# Linux machine to be converted to NAS

Tags: linux, conversion, nas

We have a (pretty old) Linux machine running crunchbang linux (64 bit). The machine was used for some time just as a storage space, files were managed mainly via SCP and SSH. But due to the increased number of requests we would like to turn that machine into a local NAS machine, without wiping out the already existing files.

Basically we want the following features:

1. a common directory for storage which can be mounted from Windows and Linux. Everyone can access it
2. a web based GUI for beginner users (just as other (commercial) NAS boxes offer)
3. a private space for users, accessible only by the specific user

Can you hint me towards:

- a list of software
- other configuration options

that should be installed/performed in order for it to be as close to the desire of our team as possible?

Comment: [Install Samba](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916212), it supports user-specific shares.

Answer (score 2):

Spiff is absolutely right about cost factors.

Anyway, [freenas](http://www.freenas.org/) should fit all your needs, if you can reinstall the machine and move existing files elsewhere during setup)

Answer (score 1):

Consider transferring your data to a dedicated NAS device. NAS hardware might use as little as 10W or less of power on average, whereas a full PC may use over an order of magnitude more power.

Using old PC hardware is attractive from the standpoint of hardware costs, but if you factor in energy costs (including cooling/air conditioning costs), plus setup/administration/maintenance costs, it's often more cost-effective in the long run to purchase embedded hardware that's easy to use.